# What are the benefits to concatenating JS files?

Tags: javascript

We recently had our video service go down and the reason revolved around a company who's plugin we used had concatenated 2 js files, but the concatenation stopped working.

They had code like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//url.com/direc1/concat-direc/file1,file2.js"></script>`

I was just wondering what the benefit *(if there even is any)* that there is to doing something like this?

**My thoughts were:**

- Speed
- Cleaner file structure
- Easier includes?
- Cuts down on the amount of script calls

Is this more beneficial then just including 2 minified JS files, like this?

```
<script src="file1"> </script>
<script src="file2"> </script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I searched "what are the benefits to concatenating JS files" before posting but didn't see the question you tagged. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ether: "JavaScript" would have probably been more useful than "JS" in your search, for future reference.

Comment: @squint very true, I just get into that groove of using 'JS' to type between colleagues. I will remember search better next time :)

Comment: No problem. I personally never use StackOverflow's search tool. I use Google, and include `site:stackoverflow.com javascript ...`, and it gives me really good results.